# Daily open won't chart on current day

Tags: pine-script

Right now I'm just trying to chart the days open as a horizontal line on an intraday chart.

```
Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
plot(Open)
```

But for some reason it's plotting the previous days open price on the current days intraday chart. This doesn't happen on a daily chart.

Maybe there's something I'm missing, or maybe I can offset the plot by the amount of candles per day.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work in the realtime bar, but on historical bars, unless you use `lookahead` as we do here for `Open2`, `security()` will return the value of the last **completed** higher TF bar.

Be very careful with the use of `lookahead`; if you use it to retrieve prices other than `open`, your script will be accessing future data on historical bars, which is misleading.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
Open = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)
Open2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open, lookahead = true)
plot(Open)
plot(Open2, "Daily Open", color.fuchsia)
```

[image]
See [this script](https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/) for a discussion on the subject.